# How can I reset the vertical scroll position in Perl using Win32::GUI?

Tags: perl, user-interface, scrollbar, position

I'm outputting something to the textfield I created using [Win32::GUI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-GUI), like this:

```
$Object->AddTextfield(
        -name   => "Birthchart",
        -left   => 75,
        -top    => 90,
        -width  => 250,
        -height => 250,
        -vscroll =>1,
        -multiline => 1,
        -prompt => "Birthchart",        
    );


    {#do something here....
     }
$Object->Birthchart->Append($Content);
```

The problem is: it automatically takes me to the end of the output but I want to read the output from the beginning without having to scroll up. It's okay to scroll down later.

I can use the following code

```
$Object->Birthchart->GetFirstVisibleLine();
```

to obtain the number of the uppermost visible line, but how can I set the number of the uppermost visible line to 0?

The code $Object->Birthchart->ResetFirstVisibleLine() doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Tried the following code

```
$Object->Birthchart->ScrollPos(1,0);
```

But it still doesn't work. The scrollbar seems to be reset but I still have to click on the scrollbar to view the beginning of the textfield content.

Comment: The best thing to do when you have the solution is to answer your own question. This way it doesn't stay "unanswered." (You're allowed to answer your own question)

Comment: But the answer is not mine. Someone elsewhere solved my problem. Is is proper that I provide this someone else' answer to my own question?

Comment: I say you post the answer you got and attribute it to the source you got it from. So you might get a little rep out of it, but maybe you deserve it for adding the answer to SO> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix to my problem:

```
my @sel =$Object->Birthchart->GetSel();
$Object->Birthchart->Append($Content);
$Object->Birthchart->SetSel(@sel);
$Object->Birthchart->ScrollCaret();
$Object->Birthchart->SetFocus();
```

The reason why ScrollPos seems to have reset the scrollbar position but the content hasn't been updated is because ScrollPos() only acts on the scrollbar. It does not update the content of the textfield.

Many thanks to Anonymous Monk @perlmonks.org :) and the original answer is [here](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=815081).